# How to prove two diagonalizable matrices are similar iff they have same eigenvalue with same multiplicity?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization, similar-matrices

$\Rightarrow$To start with, according to the similarity theorem, they have the same eigenvalues so is the multiplicity.

$\Leftarrow$If two matrices have the same eigenvalues and multiplicity, that implies they are similar to the same diagonalizable matrix $D$ and by equivalent relation, they are similar to each other.

However for the second part, since we are not sure the dim($E_{\lambda n})=$multiplicity for $\lambda_n$, how are we making sure that the two matrices are diagonalizable. If diagonalizability is not assured, my second part is wrong.

Could you offer me any hint?

Comment: The question in the title says "two diagonalizable matrices".  If that is accurate, then you have by assumption that they are diagonalizable, and you have no need to ensure this separately.  Is your question about whether $D$ is diagonalizable?

Answer (score 1):

We are *assuming* that the matrices are diagonalizable. So, instead, you should show that they are similar to the same *diagonal* matrix $D,$ and conclude from there.