# Are $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ similar?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, similar-matrices

I have two matrices:

$$
A =\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}~~~~~~~
B = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
I am to show they are similar or not similar. I set the following up:

$$
B = Q^{-1}AQ
$$
where
$$
Q = 
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{bmatrix}
$$
I solved that $d = -b$ and $c=b$ and $-b(b-a) \ne 0$. I set $b = 2$, $a =1$ and attempted to solve $B=Q^{-1}AQ$, but I end up getting:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
3 & 0 \\
3 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
I wanted to ask about my general strategy, and if at this point, I must simply plug in different values to see what works.

Calculation:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
=
\frac{1}{ad-bc}
\begin{bmatrix}
d & -b \\
-c & a
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
=
\frac{1}{ad-bc}
\begin{bmatrix}
(a+c)d & (b+d)d \\
-c(a+c) & -c(b+d)
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I then solved the linear system.

Likewise, solving $AQ = QB$, I get:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\
a & b
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\
a & b
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a+c & b+d \\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
a+b & 0 \\
c+d & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
which only gives that $b=c$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I tell if matrices are similar?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14075/how-do-i-tell-if-matrices-are-similar)

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145954/discussion-on-question-by-user129393192-are-beginbmatrix-1-0-1-0-end); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 4):

$$
A =\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
B = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$

where
$$
Q = 
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{bmatrix}
$$

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

THEN
$$
AQ =\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix} 
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{bmatrix}= 
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\
a & b
\end{bmatrix}
$$

WHILE

$$
QB = 
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}= 
\begin{bmatrix}
a & a \\
c & c
\end{bmatrix}
$$

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

Finally
$$
AQ -QB = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & b-a \\
a-c & b-c
\end{bmatrix}
$$
In order for this to be the zero matrix, we need $a=b=c.$  Once we do that,   we need to have determinant nonzero to put his back into the form $Q^{-1}  A Q.$  Well, now the determinant becomes $$ ad-bc \mapsto  ad - a^2  = a (d-a). $$
In order for this determinant to be nonzero, we must have both $a \neq 0$  and $d \neq a$

One possibility is
$$
Q = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
1 & 2
\end{bmatrix}
$$
for which
$$
Q^{-1} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
2 & -1 \\
-1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: Those are the same as what I had originally gotten. Thanks for taking the time. It seems I simply miscalculated the RHS.

Comment: @user129393192  suggest you correct the numerous errors  in your post above.

Answer (score 1):

You can realise after some progress that the benefits  of the result : $A$ and $A^T$ are similar.

Similarity have many equivalent definition:

1. $A\sim B$
2. $A, B$ represents the same linear map possibly under two different bases.
3. $A$ , $B$ have same Jordan normal form upto the permutations of jordan blocks.

You can derive a lot of interesting properties of similar matrices especially from $3$.

Checking similarity by definition quite laborious.

Answer (score -1):

Note $A, B$ are diagonalizable with the same set of eigenvalues $\lambda_1=1, \lambda_2=0$, hence, there exists invertible matrices $P_A, P_B$, such that

$$P_A^{-1}AP_A=D=P_B^{-1}BP_B$$

where

$$D =\begin{bmatrix}
\lambda_1 & 0 \\
0 & \lambda_2
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$

Therefore,

$$A=P_AP_B^{-1}BP_BP_A^{-1}=(P_BP_A^{-1})^{-1}B(P_BP_A^{-1})$$

Let $Q=P_BP_A^{-1}$, then we have

$$A=Q^{-1}BQ$$

They are similar.

Comment: I do not have that theorem. Could you please show it using the definition?

Comment: Have you learned how to diagonalize a matrix?

Comment: Not in the context of this course. We do not have the definition. I am in my second course of linear algebra, where it is all proof based.

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonalizable_matrix

Comment: This post shows the proof: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1577445/how-to-prove-two-diagonalizable-matrices-are-similar-iff-they-have-same-eigenval#:~:text=%E2%87%92To%20start%20with%2C%20according,are%20similar%20to%20each%20other. @user129393192